# How to save dropdown/checkbox menu choice AND placeholder value by clicking a unique button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I'm very newbie on Jquery, here's my problems.

1) I have a dropdown menu and a placeholder to set, by clicking on a button I'd like to save both values. This is what I wrote to save the placeholder input value, how to save and use the dropdown menu value at the same time?

```
<select name="comparison" id="comparison" size="1">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> -- </option> 
    <option value="minor"> < </option>
    <option value="equal"> = </option>
</select>
<input id="search-price" type="text" placeholder=" insert price..."/>
<button id="run-search-price">Search</button> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var runSearch = function () {
            var searchText = $('#search-price').val();        
            var queryPrice = {....}
            [...]
        };    
        $('#run-search-price').click(runSearch);
  </script>
```

2) similar problem, I have a checkbox menu and a dropdown menu, I wanna save the values to use them for my queries, how to do that?

Hope this is clear, thank you in advance and sorry for possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

When click on Search button you need both selected option and text box value. If i am correct once find [htmlCode](http://gudlakalyan.blogspot.in/2015/02/html-java-script-simple-task.html)

```js
function search(){
      alert($("#comparison option:selected").val()+$("#search-price").val() )
}
```

```html
<select name="comparison" id="comparison" size="1">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> -- </option>
    <option value="minor"> < </option>
    <option value="equal"> = </option>
</select>
<input id="search-price" type="text" placeholder=" insert price..."/>
<button id="run-search-price" onclick="search()">Search</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I went over the problem by changing something on the structure of my html page.

Comment: Fine @Marco we should fallow structure then we can feel good. enjoy and  happy coding